# In R, how to read an integer from user prompt?

Tags: r

I am trying to read an integer from user prompt. But it is reading as character. How to read it as integer?

```
myfunt <- function(){
 cat("Enter an integer or whole number : \n")
 enter <- readline(prompt = "")
 cat("You sumitted : \n"); str(enter)
}
```

Running this function produces:
    myfunt()

```
Enter an integer or whole number: 
17
You sumitted : 
chr "17"
```

Any solution?

Comment: you should have thought of it. I guess... as.integer() and problem solved.

Comment: thanks. i just did not thought of it. but sure, next time I will try on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh ! simple... just use as.integer()

```
myfunt <- function(){
 cat("Enter an integer or whole number : \n")
 enter <- as.integer(readline(prompt = ""))
 cat("You sumitted : \n"); str(enter)
}
```

and running your function.. myfunt()

```
Enter an integer or whole number: 
17
You sumitted : 
int 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally 'readline' function takes data into character value.

In order to convert these character into numeric values, you can make use of below code into your function,

If you have only one number to be converted into a numeric value,

```
num <- readline("Enter a number : ")
num <- as.numeric(unlist(num))
```

If you have multiple numbers to be converted into a numeric value,

```
num <- readline("Enter the sequence of numbers separated by comma : ")
num <- strsplit(num,',')
num <- as.numeric(unlist(num))
```